# Restricting blocks to certain URL paths without sub paths

Tags: 8, blocks

How can it be achieved, to make a block appear for the URL path `/foo/*` but not for `/foo/*/bar`?

Comment: You question doesn't explicitly say it, but are you asking about how to achieve this in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible with the default path visibility condition.

If you need that, then you need to write your own condition plugin that allows to both have a white and a blacklist instead of just one or the other.